# How to configure Mule Standalone with Netbeans 8.2 IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans, mule

How to configure Mule Standalone with Netbeans 8.2 IDE?

In Netbeans Server section i only have following list of servers and i am unable to append mule server to same:

[image]

Could anyone suggest steps to configure "mule-standalone-3.3.0" on Netbeans 8.2?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use either mule studio or eclipse to setup the projects. i prefer the later as it is easy and run the mule projects. dont use netbeans.

Comment: But How to configure Mule with Netbeans?